# F# - Matrix retreatment

Tags: f#, matrix

I have the following criterias for a user profile :

**Criteria 1 :**

1 = Man

2 = Woman

3 = Unknown

**Criteria 2 :**

1 = Yes

2 = No

**Criteria 3 :**

1 = Yes

2 = No

3 = Unknown

I have the following matrix from SQL : Matrix "User1" [[3.;1.;2.]] (Sex Unknown / Yes / No)

I would like to find a code to obtain the following retreatment and that can work if a new criteria is added (one more column for Matrix "User1" from SQL) :

Result : [[0.;0.;1.;1.;0.;0.;1.;0.]]

which is [[Man;Woman;Unknown;Yes to Criteria2;No to Criteria 2;Yes to Criteria3;No to Criteria3;Unknown to Criteria3]]

Comment: Looking at your last example, due to the way the elements are ordered, I don't see a way to do this without supplying the number of rows. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you like this?

```
//> conv [[3.;1.;2.]] ;;
//val it : float list list = [[0.0; 0.0; 1.0; 1.0; 0.0; 0.0; 1.0; 0.0]]
let conv data =
    let [[a:float;b;c]] = data
    let C1 = Array.create 3 0.
    let C2 = Array.create 2 0.
    let C3 = Array.create 3 0.
    C1.[int a - 1] <- 1.0
    C2.[int b - 1] <- 1.0
    C3.[int c - 1] <- 1.0
    [ Array.concat [| C1; C2; C3 |] |> Array.toList]
```